# Can I mock a generic (template) private method using MockK in Kotlin?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, mockk

I would like to mock the following function:

`private fun <T> updateItemInDb(id: Long, column: String, data: T)`

which is invoked in the following way by my class:

`updateItemInDb(it, DB_POS, i)`, where `it` is a `Long`, `DB_POS` is `String` and `i` is an `Int`.

I want the function to just run without doing anything. I tried the following in my unit test:

1) `every { adapter["updateItemInDb"](any<Long>(), any<String>(), any<Int>()) } just Runs`

This gives me a type mismatch error: `required MockKStubScope<Unit>, found MockKStubScope<Any?>`

2) `every { adapter["updateItemInDb"](any<Long>(), any<String>(), any<Int>()) } answers { }`

This fails at runtime with `io.mockk.MockKException: can't find function updateItemInDb(-1078155520644112829, -d008fa83c4f49c0, 843241211) for dynamic call`

Comment: I created an issue [#70](https://github.com/oleksiyp/mockk/issues/70) for it.

Comment: Version 1.7.16 should fix this issue. Please check and close GH issue [#70](https://github.com/oleksiyp/mockk/issues/70) if it is working. After you close (if so) I will write an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now yes. Generic private functions was fixed since 1.7.16